# Does an increase in max allowed items carry over?

Tags: rift

If I expand my current starter dimension (the one you get for free) in item size and buy a new one, does that carry over to the new one or is that money lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Dimension is unique.

If one buys upgrades for a dimension, they do not carry over to a different/new dimension.

However, the money is not lost since you can have multiple dimensions.